# Suppose that matrix A represents an 256 X 256 image

Tags: matrices, transformation, fourier-transform, wave-equation, wavelets

Suppose that matrix A represents an 256 X 256 image
what matrix operation would you use to produce a plot of :

a)A rotated 90 clockwise.

b) A rotated 180 counterclockwise.

c)A with its elements reflected across the main diagonal.

d)A with the first 128 columns colored gray.

please any hint or help with that I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

In general, most of these geometrical operations on matrices are trivially found by combining transposition (i.e. rotating through the diagonal) and flip permutation (rotating through a mid vertical line). That is the reason the next expressions are quite similar.

Let have the permutation matrix $P_{i_1... i_n}=[e_{i_1} ... e_{i_n}]$ with $e_{i}$ the column base vector with a 1 at the $i$th row, and $D_{d_1... d_n}$ the diagonal matrix with $d_i$ as the diagonal $i$th position. 
Lets assume the image maps in $[0,1]$.

a) $A' P_{n...1}$

b) $P_{n...1} A P_{n...1}$

c) $A'$

d) $A D_{d_1...d_n}$  with $d_1...d_{n/2}=1/2$ and $d_{n/2+1}...d_n=1$

Let try the following example in [Octave](https://octave-online.net/) for $\mathbb{R}^4$:

```
% Simple Example
n=4;
A=rand(n,n);
P=fliplr(eye(n));
D=diag([0.5 0.5 1 1]);
A1=A'*P,A2=P*A*P,A3=A',A4=A*D
```

Comment: what do you mean by A`? THANK YOU

Comment: The matrix transpose of course!.......

Comment: Do you need a simpler example on the other matrices???

Comment: YES, I appreciate

Comment: As this is probably an assignment I think it would be better if you explained why these are the answer. Just producing answer to other peoples homework is not going to benefit anybody. Besides the answer to (d) is probably incorrect.

Comment: No, this is correct. Check the given code. An explanation is given why those operators are used.